# Automaticly make a profile when user registers (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a profile page for my registered users.
On this page the Auth\User data will be displayed (Name, Email) but also extra profile information (city, country, phone number, ..).

I've already made the one to one relationship but I'm having one issue.
When a User gets created, I would like to automaticly have a Profile created for that specific user.

At the moment I simply added the profile for my first user through tinker, but as soon as I made a second user & went to the profile page, it gave an error (seeing the profile had not been made yet).

In the Profile.php I have:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model {

    protected $table = 'profiles';
    protected $fillable = ['city', 'country', 'telephone'];

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

In the User.php I added:

```
<?php namespace App;

...

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    ...

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'lastname', 'email', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];


    public function Profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }
}
```

I show the Profile data like this (on my profile.blade.php page):

```
Full name: {{ Auth::user()->name }} {{ Auth::user()->lastname }}
E-Mail Address: {{ Auth::user()->email}}


City: {{ Auth::User()->profile->city}}
Country: {{ Auth::User()->profile->country}}
Phone number: {{ Auth::User()->profile->telephone}}
```

I'm guessing I need to add something to the 'AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers' trait and the 'Registrar.php' service, but I have no idea what.

Thanks,

Cedric

Comment: Do you have a separate user profile view and the associated route?

Comment: Yes, I made a profile.blade.php and have the route set through:
Route::get('/profile', 'PagesController@profile');

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: I don't know how to automaticly make the profile (on my profile table) once the user is made, therefor I get an error on my profile page (unless I make the profile manually through tinker).

Comment: Why not just combine the user and profile models into the same user model?

Comment: I want to make the profile data editable.

Comment: How would combining the tables make the profile not editable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments on your question I believe the best answer here is to combine the two models into one User model.

However, if you want to create a relationship on your user when it is created you can modify the Registrar service.

The `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait will use the registrar (located in `app/Services/Registrar.php` by default) to validate and register users.

You can just modify the `create` method in there to automatically create the profile relation at the same time:

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
    $user->profile()->save(new Profile);
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Seeing I'm pretty new at Laravel 5, I haven't found the way to edit the Auth::user() data. This is why I opted to make a relationship.

It may be far fetched but this is the only way I would know how to edit the profile data.

Comment: Auth::user() simply gives you the user model for the currently logged in user. Since it's an eloquent model you can make any changes you want. like $user = Auth::user(); $user->email = 'example@fake.com'; $user->save();

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll give it a try. Been busy with other things concirning my project.
Thanks & I'll keep you posted.

Comment: i' dont think this is gonna work. It shouldnt be reachable

Answer (score 2):

There are three options that come to my mind.

#### Combine User and Profile tables

Why are you separating the user account from the profile? I can't think of a good reason to (not saying there isn't one, I just can't think of one). Combining the tables would save you database queries and completely resolve this issue. I think this would be the best option.

#### Use model event.

Create a listener on the User::created event.

```
User::created(function(User $user) {
    $user->profile->save(Profile::create([... ]));
});
```

#### Use a repository

Create a user repository to manage all the data base querying. Then in the repository create method you can manually create the profile record and associate the two. Then use the repository in the Registrar instead of the Model directly

Comment: Wouldn't a good reason be performance? You wouldn't always wish to be accessing the profile info when all you want is to auth user?

Comment: @StevenGrant are you talking about performance for the first reason? If so then no; performance is negligible. If you're just authenticating you can just select the appropriate fields `SELECT email,password...`. Even if you return the whole role, profile and all, it shouldn't cause any significant performance issues.

Comment: User object loaded wherever auth is used, so having extra data there when not needed could (at a certain point granted) slow your app down