# How to make RegisterController's create method generate a Profile entry in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

The user's details are stored in two separate tables `User` and `Profile`.

I'm using Laravel's built-in authentication, i.e.:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Once the user registers, I wish that apart from a `User` entry being created, an accompanying `Profile` entry (with all values set to null) is created and linked to the `User` entry by means of a FK.

The user is then redirected to a page where he can fill in the `Profile` details.

```
// create_users_table.php

Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('username')->unique();
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});

// create_profiles_table.php

Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->date('date_of_birth');
    $table->string('city');
});
```

I'm guessing the corresponding `Profile` object must be instantiated and saved when the `RegisterController`'s `create` function is invoked.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

**Where do I create and save the corresponding Profile object?**

[This question has already been asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608069/automaticly-make-a-profile-when-user-registers-laravel-5) One member suggested making changes to `app/Services/Registrar.php`, but Laravel 5.4.0 doesn't seem to have the said file. Does anyone know where the equivalent code he's referring to can be found in 5.4.0?

Comment: If a user will only ever have one profile, it's probably better to put the profile data right in the user model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to make things easier, let's define the `profile()` relationship in your User's model. 
So, in `App\User`, you would have something like this.

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class); 
}
```

I am assuming that a User has only one profile. If they have many, please update the relationship accordingly.

Then, in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController`, you would override the `create()` method as such:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    // Creates the user profile
    $profile = Profile::create([
        //
    ]); 

    // Associates the relationship
    $user->profile()->save($profile); 

    // This, of course, assumes you have 
    // the above relationship defined in your user model.

    return $user; 
}
```

Alternatively, you could hook into the User's model events. 
In your `App\User` class's `boot()` method, you would have something like this.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot(); 

    static::created(function ($user)) {
        $profile = Profile::create([
            //
        ]); 

        $user->profile()->save($profile); 
    }); 
}
```

Now, each time a User is created, a corresponding profile is also associated.

Comment: Hi thanks your original answer was enough! Solved it for me immediately! Relationships and the rest of the plumbing was already taken care of :-) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Done. Thanks ;)