# laravel not updating data, just refresh

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

hello i have two tables users and profiles and i have a form to update the user profile, whene i try to update, it's just refresh the page but nothing was updated, and there is no errors
this is my code :

ProfilesControllers:

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[

            'name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'about'=>'required',
            'facebook'=>'required|url',
            'instagram'=>'required|url',
        ]);

        $user = Auth::user();
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){

            $avatar = $request->avatar;

            $avatar_new_name = time() . $avatar->getClientOriginalName();

            $avatar->move('uploads/avatars', $avatar_new_name);

            $user->profile->avatar = 'uploads/avatars'.$avatar_new_name;

            $user->profile->save();
        }
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->profile->facebook = $request->facebook;
        $user->profile->instagram = $request->instagram;
        $user->profile->about = $request->about;
        

        if($request->has('password')){
            $user->password=bcrypt($request->password);
            $user->save();

        }

        $user->save();
        $user->profile->save($user->profile);

        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

profile.blade.php :

```
    <form action="{{ route('user.profile.update')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
        {{ csrf_field() }}
       
/// here is my input fields
    
    </form>
```

and i'm using Laravel : 6.20.5
could someone tell me where is the problem in my code? thanks

Comment: Change `$user = Auth::user();` to `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);`

Comment: @sta sorry, still have the same problem even if i do this

Comment: Did you check whether the update method is triggered or not? I mean you can `dd($request->all())` in the update method and check

Comment: @Donkarnash yes i have try dd($request->all()) and i can see my data in the screen

Comment: And have you checked that it passes validation as well. Does a dd after the validation also gets executed

Comment: @Donkarnash Sorry i don't understand your point i'm a beginner in laravel !

Comment: If you put a `dd('validation passed')` after the $this->validate() , do you see the string "validation passed" on screen - this is just to check if validation passes. Cause if validation fails and you don't have validation errors displayed in blade view then it will be just like page gets refreshed and nothing happens at database level

Comment: @Donkarnash yes it's a problem with the validation because when i remove it , i can update normally

Comment: I thought so - validation fails. For an update request there may be fields which are not required for eg: facebook, instagram urls may not change and may not be required so change the validation rules to `sometimes` or `nullable` from `required`

Comment: @Donkarnash yes everything working now thank you for your time

Comment: I think, the validation is the issue. Make  `dd($request->all())` after the validation and let me know what happen?

Comment: @Donkarnash i have resolved the problem of validation, i'm facing another one when a new user registered he can not update his profile because his id is not in the profiles table. so i get this error : Indirect modification of overloaded property App\User::$profile has no effect,

Comment: In that case you need to save the user first and then create the profile within the same method. If you want help on that you can post the code of method which you are using when registering a new user along with profile data and I can suggest - but I think it should be done in a new question and you can leave me a tagged comment here with link to the new question

Comment: @Donkarnash thanks for your valuable time i found a reply here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608069/automaticly-make-a-profile-when-user-registers-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

instead of  $avatar = $request->avatar;

use

```
$avatar = $request->file('avatar');
```

and instead of $avatar->move('uploads/avatars', $avatar_new_name);

use

```
$request->file('avatar')->storeAs('uploads/avatars', $avatar_new_name);
```

and when using back() there's no need for redirect(). back() generates an HTTP redirect.

so

```
return back();
```

Comment: thank you, but still facing tha same problem, the page refresh but nothing updating in the database

Comment: Hmm... could be a validation problem. Try getting rid of your validation code at first. See if it changes anything.

Comment: thank you its working, you'r right its somthing in the validation

Comment: ok. find what's wrong and apply the correction in my answer above. Should be working :)